# Background image without using background-image

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm using a third party commercial framework which doesn't seem to read the background-image property, yet I need to place an image at the background of the product I'm creating.
I tried using the z-index to place the image behind the text, but it didn't seem to work either.

I don't have a load of experience with html, could anyone suggest a 'hacky' way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption

Using the `<figcaption>` you can set an image an the text wherever you want on the image using css

```
<figure>
  <img src="imageSrc" alt="" />
  <figcaption>Your Image Text</figcaption>
</figure>
```